# Is there a way to add another function reference parameter to this JQuery call in CoffeeScript without using a line for each parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, coffeescript

Is there a way to add `error:` parameter to this line without using a single parameter per line format?

```
$.ajax type:'DELETE', url: '/history', data: {id: id}, success: (data)->
  $('#row'+index).detach()
```

I know I can turn it into

```
$.ajax
  type: 'DELETE'
  url: '/history'
  data: id: id
  success: (data) ->
    $('#row' + index).detach()
  error: ->
    alert 'Error'
```

But I wanted to try to learn more of the intricacies of CoffeeScript syntax. I know I can use parenthesis for `$.post` but that allows chaining callbacks, which is different than this `$.ajax` format.

```
$.post("/history", {food: food, size: size, unit: unit}, (data)->
  alert 'Success'
).fail ->
  alert 'Fail'
```

I tried the following, but it never called the success callback:

```
$.ajax type:'DELETE', url: '/history', data: {id: id}, 
  success: (data)->
    alert 'Success'
    $('#row'+index).detach()
  error: ->
    alert "Could not delete the food."
```

---

This worked!

```
$.ajax type:'DELETE', url: '/history', data: {id: id}, success: ((data)->
  $('#row'+tmpIndex).detach()
), error: ->
  alert "Could not delete the food."
```

Comment: I don't know coffeescript, but I'll bet you need a comma between the success function and `error:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delight in writing incomprehensible code that will fill whoever gets stuck maintaining your code with burning hatred, you could just add parentheses:

```
$.ajax type:'DELETE', url: '/history', data: {id: id}, success: ((data)-> ...), error: (-> ...)
```

But please don't do this. You'd be better off with the multi-line version or using named functions:

```
success = (data) ->
    # ...
error = ->
    # ...
$.ajax type:'DELETE', url: '/history', data: {id: id}, success: success, error: error
```

I prefer to avoid anonymous functions that are longer than a couple lines anyway, the indentation gets confusing very fast.

Comment: I don't like to waste newlines. But I do like named functions! But I don't like 1 line named functions.

Comment: But scrolling costs time. I would flip my monitor vertical if it would. (Have in the past.)

Answer (score 1):

Your example compiles to...

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'DELETE',
  url: '/history',
  data: {
    id: id
  }
}, {
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Success');
    return $('#row' + index).detach();
  },
  error: function() {
    return alert("Could not delete the food.");
  }
});
```

You could do this...

```
$.ajax type:'DELETE', url: '/history', data: {id: id}
  ,success: (data) ->
    alert 'Success'
    $('#row'+index).detach()
  ,error: ->
    alert "Could not delete the food."
```

...but I don't think it's good practice.

If your goal is to understand how coffeescript works, I suggest playing around with the live parser on the website for example: http://coffeescript.org/#try:

**Sidenote:** All jquery ajax functions (post/get/ajax) return promises, which have many benefits over the usual callbacks. More on that here: https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970

Comment: It's weird that HAML & Ruby need the punctuation `,` or `&&` at the end of the line, but CoffeeScript needs it at the beginning.